# Click disabled object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I set the text object in front of all.
(The text is 'connecting' that is shown during network accessing)

The text is UI on Canvas.
And also I want to enable the object clickable behind the text.
Normally click event is taken by UI Text because it's in front of all.
I want to set the text in front of all, but click is disabled (want behind object to receive click event).

Like html/css,
pointer-events: none;

Or javascript,
Propagation next event.

Answer (score 0):

Disable raycast target on the text so it wont catch the input.